# Sum most recent entries of an ever-increasing .csv file MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, function, loops, csv, timer

How can I sum the 100 most recent values in the second column of a .csv file?

The .csv file is constantly updated with a new row every minute, containing a new value. i.e the row dimension is forever increasing every minute. Assume I may accumulate 200 values, i.e 200 rows of data after 200 minutes (from external processes) but I only want to sum the 100 most recently added values (i.e from the last row of the file backwards up 99 rows)).

I have 3 sets of values, 1 value in each column. `Col2Value` is the value in Column 2 of the .csv file. The file i'm appending to is called `'200 mins.csv'`

```
dlmwrite('200 mins.csv', [Col1Value, Col2Value,Col3Value], '-append');
```

Here's a snippet of the csv file after 8 minutes of run-time i.e 8 values in column 2:

[image]

I know that MATLAB has to read the whole file first, but that's fine. I can deal with that, my application is not resource critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an array in Matlab, you can sum the last 100 elements with

```
last100sum = sum(A(end-99:end));
```

So if reading in your .csv file gives you a 2D array (which I will call `wholeFile`), and you want the sum of the last 100 elements in column 2, you do it like this:

```
last100sum2 = sum(wholeFile(end-99:end, 2));
```

If the routine you use for reading the file returns a cell array, you need to convert the cell array to a regular array first - perhaps using `cell2mat` if it contains only values (as opposed to strings, for example).

Finally - if you want to read "at most" 100 values, but there might not be 100 rows, then do the following:

```
sz = size(wholeFile);
firstRow = max(sz(1) - 99, 1); % will return 1 if fewer than 100 rows are found
atMost100sum = sum(wholeFile(firstRow:end, 2));
```

Any questions - please ask.